# __builtin_va_arg (for pointer to pointer)

Tags: ios, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

I have a code which extracts the arguments of a method.

```
va_list argp2; 
va_start(argp2, sel);

NSURLResponse* obj = va_arg(*argp2,NSURLResponse**);
```

the argp2 contains the arguments for the method 
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error]

I would like to convert argp2 to get a pointer to response and error objects.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using stdargs at all, it looks like you have a call with fixed arguments?  The problem, btw, is you should be declaring `NSURLResponse** obj`  the va_arg call is returning a double-pointer whereas obj is only a single-pointer.

Comment: Please show a complete self-contained example to make your question clear. The `*` in `va_arg(*argp2, ..)` makes no sense - perhaps that was an attempt to make the code appear in **bold face** ?

Comment: I have tried this but error :
`NSURLResponse ** obj = va_arg(*argp2,NSURLResponse **);`
It says : Pointer to non-const type NSURLResponse* with no explicit ownership

Comment: Martin, Yes the * makes no sense, I have tried to remove it but no success

Comment: @user3545664: It is difficult to help without more context. As David said above, va_list is only used in the context of a variable argument list. Please show a complete method where the va_list is used, and also how this method is called.