# Extract args from CompletationBlock

Tags: ios, block, extract

I have defined a type named CompletionHandlerBlock

```
typedef void (^CompletionHandlerBlock)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error);
```

This is for the method :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest2 queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"completed");
}
];
```

I would like to use va_start and va_arg functions to detect dynamically the values of the args passed in the completation block (completionHandler).

I have tried :

```
CompletionHandlerBlock obj2 = va_arg(*argp,CompletionHandlerBlock);
//now obj2 contains the CompletionHandler block object
va_list argp2;
va_start(argp2, obj2);
for(id obj = obj2; obj; obj = va_arg(argp2, id)) {
     NSLog(@"obj:%@",obj);
}
va_end(argp2);
```

But no success.
The point is to get NSResponse, NSData and NSError objects.

Thanks

Comment: Is this the same as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741425/builtin-va-arg-for-pointer-to-pointer? - How to you intercept the calls?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. The NSURLConnection code calls the block with arguments. Inside the block (which you provide), it has access to the values of the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use va_arg at all except in a function or method or block with variable number of arguments, that is one declared with ... as the last parameter. So whatever you are trying to do, it cannot possibly work.

On the other hand, it is highly unclear *what* you are actually trying to achieve. response, data and error are already parameters to the completion block. You should really write the complete code that you tried to use, not just a code fragment without any context.

Comment: I'm working on automated monitoring library which intercepts dynamically all NSURLConnection class connections. The question is how to get arguments values from obj2 in this case (with va_start or without it).
Suppose you have this variable. How could you access to its arguments ?
`CompletionHandlerBlock obj2 = va_arg(*argp,CompletionHandlerBlock);`